# Upgrade to 4.0: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: linq, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, reference, upgrade

I recently upgraded my solution from .net framework 3.5 to 4.0. All good except it gives me some errors in my website project.

```
The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Xml'
(are you missing an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'Script' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' 
(are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Here is what my web.config looks like:

```
<add assembly="System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
<add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<!--vjslib is needed for Google Transit-related code-->
<add assembly="vjslib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
<add assembly="Infragistics35.WebUI.Shared.v10.2, Version=10.2.20102.1011, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"/>
<add assembly="Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v10.2, Version=10.2.20102.1011, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb"/>
<add assembly="Infragistics35.WebUI.UltraWebTab.v10.2, Version=10.2.20102.1011, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
<add assembly="Infragistics35.Web.v10.2, Version=10.2.20102.1011, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7DD5C3163F2CD0CB"/>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
<add assembly="mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
<add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
```

Why is it not able to find LINQ reference when i say `using System.Linq` or `System.Xml.Linq`? What am i missing here?

--Edit--

This happens only in website project. Other class libraries work fine.

Comment: I don't see reference to the System.Core

Comment: sorry. missed one line from the assembly section.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a ASP.NET 3.5 WebSite project which I've tried to upgrade to .NET v4. Got the error. 
My solution:

1. Go to WebSite project property pages and set it back to . NET v3.5
2. Compile and see all is OK
3. Switch it back to .NET v4
4. Compile and see all is OK

Answer (score 2):

Have you chose the right framework. I think in your project file on the first tab ".NET Framework 4 Client Profile" is chosen. Take ".NET Framework 4"

Comment: Yes. Target framework is Framework 4.0 and not the client profile

Comment: Sometimes good 'ol VisualStudio get's in a mess with the references. It seems that VS is having a kind of cache. What helped me: Remove all references from the project, close visual studio, reopen Visual Studio, open project and add the required references.

Comment: I did all that. I cleared all cache, temp asp.net files etc. Finally i converted everything back to 3.5 and re-compiled and then converted it to 4.0 and it worked. Thanks for your help tho.